# Trying to TryParse in c++/clr but OUT is undefined

Tags: c++-cli, clr

im trying to use

```
       public: bool^ IsNumeric(Object^ Expression) {
           double^ retNum;
           bool^ isNum = Double::TryParse(Convert::ToString(Expression), System::Globalization::NumberStyles::Any, System::Globalization::NumberFormatInfo::InvariantInfo, out retNum);
           return isNum;
       }
```

but i get a error: identifer OUT is undefined
i have no idea how to use OUT in clr/c++
Thanks

Comment: yes, i get error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2665 'System::Double::TryParse': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types Project1 C:\Users\Tewni\source\repos\Project1\Project1\MyForm.h 410

Comment: [Tracking Reference Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions)

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

retNum was null.

Comment: The tracking reference operator is `%`, so use `%retNum`. And `retNum` should not be declared with `^`.

Comment: Knowing when to use the ^ hat is super-duper important, hard to make progress in C++/CLI when that's still murky.  bool and double are value types, not object types, and variables of those types must therefore not be declared with ^.  With the hat, it becomes a boxed copy of the value (System.ValueType under the hood) and the compiler is liable to lose its marbles badly.

Comment: i had to use *
and i had to set the double value to 0.0
tysm

Answer (score -2):

Use "%" instead of `out` to take a tracking reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019